# Storing variables in array?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I need to find the deviation of multiple homework values. In order to do this, i need to store a variable homework, that is in a for loop, so it deletes itself every time it executes. Also, the number of variables i need in order to store the seperate homework score values is unknown, so i can't just make a list of variables. I think what i need to do is do a list of arrays, but im not sure if im doing it right.

here is the code of the method that includes the array i have created...

```
 public double computeHomeworkDeviation(int homework){
    int[] homeworkScore = new int[totalStudents];
    if(computeHomeworkDeviationCounter < totalStudents){
        homeworkScore[computeHomeworkDeviationCounter] = homework;
        computeHomeworkDeviationCounter++;
    }
    else{
        for(int k = 1; k <= totalStudents; k++){
            top += Math.pow(homeworkScore[totalStudents - k] -    homeworkAverage, 2);
        }
    homeworkDeviation = Math.sqrt(top / totalStudents); 
    }
    return homeworkDeviation;
}
```

this method is called to a for loop and calls the argument of the homework variable that needs to be stored in an array list. What i have isn't working, what am i doing wrong?
(i don't believe the array values are even being stored)

edit:
I now split it into 2 methods.

setArrayMethod...

```
 public void setHomeworkArray(int homework){
    homeworkScore[l] = homework;
    l++;
}
```

computeHomeworkDeviationMethod...

```
 public double computeHomeworkDeviation(int homework){
        for(int k = 1; k <= totalStudents; k++){
            top += Math.pow(homeworkScore[totalStudents - k] -          homeworkAverage, 2);
        }
    homeworkDeviation = Math.sqrt(top / totalStudents); 
    return homeworkDeviation;
    }
```

am getting ArrayOutOfBoundsException error still.

Comment: `What i have isn't working,` Not working in which sense. error? wrong output? what

Comment: I am getting the wrong value for homeworkDeviation and i believe it has something to do with storing the homework values in the array.

Comment: move `int[] homeworkScore = new int[totalStudents];` outside the function

Comment: where is `computeHomeworkDeviationCounter ` declared?

Comment: There is only one array assignment in your code. Your for loop does not assign anything

Comment: i did that, and now i get an error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is correct, the values aren't storing properly. I'm not sure what exactly you want your program to do but I think you'd want a loop instead of `if` when storing values in the array:

```
while(computeHomeworkDeviationCounter < totalStudents){
    homeworkScore[computeHomeworkDeviationCounter] = homework;
    computeHomeworkDeviationCounter++;
}
```

This also means you'll have to remove the `else` statement. Finally, to avoid errors if this method is executed several times, I recommend resetting the variables `computeHomeworkDeviationCounter` when the method is called:

```
public double computeHomeworkDeviation(int homework){
int[] homeworkScore = new int[totalStudents];
computeHomeworkDeviationCounter = 0;
```

...or even having it as a method-local variable if it isn't used anywhere else:

```
public double computeHomeworkDeviation(int homework){
int[] homeworkScore = new int[totalStudents];
int computeHomeworkDeviationCounter = 0;
```

And likewise for the variable `top` if appropriate for the rest of your program.

Comment: i edited my submission...also, the values do not need to be reset in the code.